# How to place the image above the slider in mobile view in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, slider

I'm making a responsive page in which i have an image and a range slider . Initially(Desktop view) , the image is placed at the right of the range slider.But in mobile view image is over-lapping with the slider.

I have already tried to fix this problem but again it keeps on coming in the right of the slider but I want the image to come on top of the slider , when in mobile view.

here's some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="draft.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="header text-center">Heading</h1>


    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Choose
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <div class="slidecontainer">
            <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="inputknobs">
        </div>
        <div class="slidecontainer">
            <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="inputknobs">
        </div>
        <div class="slidecontainer">
            <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="inputknobs">
        </div>
        <div >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="sub_btn">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="output">
        <img src="graph_area.png" class="img-fluid float-right" id="op_pic">
    </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body{
    margin-top:1rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

.input{
    margin-top: 3rem;
}
#inputknobs{
    padding:1rem;
}
#sub_btn{
    margin-top: 2rem !important;
}
#op_pic{
    max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left:25rem;
  margin-top:-20rem;
  width:50%;
}
```

So when in mobile view the image should come on top of the sliders rather than coming to its right. Please help me with this Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using grid columns as Bootstrap intended. It's not the image that's overlapping, but the sliders. Add a row and columns and it works. You do need to remove some of the image styling to let the grid do its thing.

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/q2cmv61k/)**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="header text-center">Heading</h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Choose
        </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <div class="slidecontainer">
                    <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="inputknobs">
                </div>
                <div class="slidecontainer">
                    <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="inputknobs">
                </div>
                <div class="slidecontainer">
                    <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="inputknobs">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="sub_btn">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="output">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img-fluid float-right" id="op_pic">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that I did not fix column ordering (to get the image on top). See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#order-classes for that.

Comment: I tried what you said , but now the image disappeared until i shrink the window. When the window is small only then image is displaying.